# "adb devices" can't recognize my G-Tide E56

Tags: android, adb

I have a G-Tide E56 running android 2.3.9
The "adb devices" command can't find my device , I've tried all the solutions I've found
for other devices but still no result, because I can't find a single answer regarding the G-Tide E56 specifically. Can any one point me to start. I'm Using a mac running OSX 10.7.4

Things I've tried: 
1. check USB debugging enabled on the device 
2. update adb 
3. restart adb (kill-server, start-server)

The USB mass Storage is working perfectly so I'm sure there is nothing wrong with the USB port

Comment: There is definitely USB driver missing for ADB but I have no idea where to find it. Google can't say anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

1. Be sure that USB Debugging is enabled on the device
2. Windows Key + R -> `devmgmt.msc`
3. Find the connected device and right click

   1. Update Driver Software
   2. Browse...
   3. Let me pick...
   4. Next...
   5. Have Disk...
   6. %AndroidSKDLocation%`/extras/google/usb_driver/android_winusb.inf`
   7. Open

See if this works, this will try and use the Android SDK Default ADB driver.

**EDIT** My DROID4 will only work in ADB connected mode if the USB connection is set to type `MTP` / `Media Device`, so try chaning you USB Connection modes and running `adb devices` while in each one.

Comment: I've mentioned that I'm using a Mac with OSX 10.7 !!
Also I've tried earlier to test it on a windows but I couldn't even get the USB recognized for mass storage there is something terrible about this device drivers I guess and I couldn't find any help doing a search.

Also I've tried all the USB modes (Charge Only, USB Tethering, USB Storage) nothing is working.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tryed going to were your adb.exe and clicking it. it will run really fast than dissapear worked once for me.Aldo another time I had to go into the task manager and kill the currently running adb

The USB drivers can be found in your sdk manager under extras

Comment: The OP stated that the command `adb devices` return no results, so the ADB daemon is running, and that he has also already tried killing and restarting the adb server.

Comment: @MattClark I guess it is just an addition..not an answer :)

Comment: @BRK Thanks, I appreciate it but as Matt said I mentioned that I've restarted the adb.